# combining static features with temporal data in LSTM

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

I have a question about combining time-series data with static features. Static features are not temporal. In other words, they do not have a sequential nature. To clarify my question, take the following example: I want to predict the number of people in a street that are going into an event. I have two different data set: the first dataset is about the number of people in previous time steps before an event happened. The second dataset is static features that are related to that event such as event type, popularity level, subject popularity, etc. I want to combine these two datasets in LSTM. As static features have a direct impact on temporal features. How I can use that? Any comments, related links and papers would be appreciated.

Comment: You can tile the features along the time dimension and concatenated them either to LSTM input or to the LSTM output. Anyway, this does not really look like a coding question, it might be better to ask at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how I can concatenate those static features into LSTM before getting the output. Do you think with adding static features to temporal features at first, I pollute the input and make hard prediction for LSTM?